# Using a subquery in the WHERE clause of gapfill in TimescaleDB

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, timescaledb

I would like to run the gapfill function of timescaleDB in a way, where the start and end dates are generated automatically. For example, I would like to run the gapfill function between the largest and the lowest entries in the database.

Given dataset playground:

```
CREATE TABLE public.playground (
    value1 numeric,
    "timestamp" bigint,
    name "char"
);

INSERT INTO playground(name, value1, timestamp)
VALUES ('test', 100, 1599100000000000000);

INSERT INTO playground(name, value1, timestamp)
VALUES ('test', 100, 1599100001000000000);

INSERT INTO playground(name, value1, timestamp)
VALUES ('test', 100, 1599300000000000000);
```

I have tried getting the data as such:

```
SELECT time_bucket_gapfill(300E9::BIGINT, timestamp) as bucket
FROM playground
WHERE 
    timestamp >= (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(timestamp), 0) FROM playground)
    AND
    timestamp < (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(timestamp), 0) FROM playground)
GROUP BY bucket
```

I get an error:

`ERROR:  missing time_bucket_gapfill argument: could not infer start from WHERE clause`

If I try the query with hard coded timestamps, the query runs just fine.
For example:

```
SELECT time_bucket_gapfill(300E9::BIGINT, timestamp) as bucket
FROM playground
WHERE timestamp >= 0 AND timestamp < 15900000000000000
GROUP BY bucket
```

Another approach of providing the start and end dates as arguments in the gapfill function fails as well.

```
 WITH bounds AS (
  SELECT COALESCE(MIN(timestamp), 0) as min, COALESCE(MAX(timestamp), 0) as max
  FROM playground
  WHERE timestamp >= 0 AND timestamp < 15900000000000000
),
gapfill as(
SELECT time_bucket_gapfill(300E9::BIGINT, timestamp, bounds.min, bounds.max) as bucket
FROM playground, bounds
GROUP BY bucket
)
select * from gapfill
```

`ERROR:  invalid time_bucket_gapfill argument: start must be a simple expression`

Comment: for infering start and stop from WHERE clause only direct column references are supported, so in your case you have to add them to the param list ,

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please give an example? I have tried `SELECT time_bucket_gapfill(300E9::BIGINT, timestamp) as bucket, COALESCE(MIN(timestamp), 0) as min, COALESCE(MAX(timestamp), 0) as max
`, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Jani Following the suggestion: can you put the subqueries into FROM clause and then reference from there? Basically you will get join.

Comment: @k_rus, having `SELECT time_bucket_gapfill(300E9::BIGINT, timestamp) as bucket
FROM (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(timestamp), 0) as min, COALESCE(MAX(timestamp), 0) as max
        FROM  playground
) AS time_range, playground
WHERE timestamp >= time_range.min AND timestamp < time_range.max
GROUP BY bucket` also gives me the same error.

Comment: Have you tried to put `time_range.max` and `time_range.min` into the arguments of `time_bucket_gapfill`? If it doesn't work, then it might be good to create an issue in GitHub for TimescaleDB.

Comment: BTW can it be a problem with time? I don't know if PG decides different type for the expressions. Can you expand your post with the other tries where you explicitly provide the start and stop and which errors do you get?

Comment: If I explicitly define the start and stop, the query runs without any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time_bucket_gapfill` only accepts `start` and `finish` values, which can be evaluated to constants at the query planning time. So it works to provide expression with constants and `now`, however it doesn't work to access a table in the expressions.

While this limitation on `time_bucket_gapfill` is in place it is not possible to achieve the desired behaviour in a single query. The work around is to calculate values for `start` and `finish` separately and then provide the values into the query with `time_bucket_gapfill`, which can be done in a stored procedure or in the application.

A side note, if [`PREPARE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-prepare.html) will be used in PostgreSQL 12, it is important to explicitly [disable generic plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-PLAN-CACHE_MODE) for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

for inferring start and stop from WHERE clause only direct column references are supported

see : https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1345

so something like that might work , ( I have no timescaleDB access to test)
but try this :

```
SELECT
    time_bucket_gapfill(300E9::BIGINT, time_range.min , time_range.max ) AS bucket
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COALESCE(MIN(timestamp), 0)   AS min
            , COALESCE(MAX(timestamp), 0) AS max
        FROM
            playground
    ) AS time_range
    , playground
WHERE
    timestamp >= time_range.min
    AND timestamp < time_range.max
GROUP BY
    bucket;
```

Comment: So, it is not possible to do it directly from SQL? What do you think is the best way to do it then? Should I run a separate query to get the min and max values and then run the main query with those arguments?

Comment: I have tried running your code. Unfortunately it doesn't work either. I get `ERROR:  invalid time_bucket_gapfill argument: start must be a simple expression`